# Why does Java Compilation fail when trying to build for android and Openfl

Tags: android, javac, haxe, openfl

I have a very basic project using Haxe and OpenFL. I'm trying to test on the android emulator by running the following command.

`openfl test android -emulator`

My project is going to be using the facebook native extension for openfl that is found on haxelibs.

I get the following stack that looks like from the javac compiler. I'm wondering if maybe its a Java version problem.

Here is my current Java version information.

```
java version "1.7.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)
```

Here is the stacktrace

```
:deps:facebook:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
    :deps:facebook:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
    /Users/matthew.wallace/Dropbox/dev/haxe/HelloWorld/Export/android/release/bin/deps/facebook/src/org/haxe/extension/facebook/AccessTokenWrapper.java:6: error: package com.facebook does not exist
    import com.facebook.AccessToken;
                       ^
    /Users/matthew.wallace/Dropbox/dev/haxe/HelloWorld/Export/android/release/bin/deps/facebook/src/org/haxe/extension/facebook/AccessTokenWrapper.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
        public static String getPermissions(AccessToken token){
                                            ^
      symbol:   class AccessToken
      location: class AccessTokenWrapper
    /Users/matthew.wallace/Dropbox/dev/haxe/HelloWorld/Export/android/release/bin/deps/facebook/src/org/haxe/extension/facebook/AccessTokenWrapper.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
        public static String getDeclinedPermissions(AccessToken token){
                                                    ^
      symbol:   class AccessToken
      location: class AccessTokenWrapper
    /Users/matthew.wallace/Dropbox/dev/haxe/HelloWorld/Export/android/release/bin/deps/facebook/src/org/haxe/extension/facebook/AppInviteDialogWrapper.java:5: error: package com.facebook.share.model does not exist
    import com.facebook.share.model.AppInviteContent;
                                   ^
    /Users/matthew.wallace/Dropbox/dev/haxe/HelloWorld/Export/android/release/bin/deps/facebook/src/org/haxe/extension/facebook/AppInviteDialogWrapper.java:6: error: package com.facebook.share.widget does not exist
    import com.facebook.share.widget.AppInviteDialog;
                                    ^
    /Users/matthew.wallace/Dropbox/dev/haxe/HelloWorld/Export/android/release/bin/deps/facebook/src/org/haxe/extension/facebook/Facebook.java:20: error: package com.facebook does not exist
    import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
                       ^
    /Users/matthew.wallace/Dropbox/dev/haxe/HelloWorld/Export/android/release/bin/deps/facebook/src/org/haxe/extension/facebook/Facebook.java:21: error: package com.facebook does not exist
    import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
                       ^
    /Users/matthew.wallace/Dropbox/dev/haxe/HelloWorld/Export/android/release/bin/deps/facebook/src/org/haxe/extension/facebook/Facebook.java:22: error: package com.facebook.appevents does not exist
    import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;
                                 ^
    /Users/matthew.wallace/Dropbox/dev/haxe/HelloWorld/Export/android/release/bin/deps/facebook/src/org/haxe/extension/facebook/Facebook.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
        CallbackManager mCallbackManager;
        ^
      symbol:   class CallbackManager
      location: class Facebook
    /Users/matthew.wallace/Dropbox/dev/haxe/HelloWorld/Export/android/release/bin/deps/facebook/src/org/haxe/extension/facebook/Facebook.java:72: error: cannot find symbol
        public CallbackManager getCallbackManager() {
               ^
      symbol:   class CallbackManager
      location: class Facebook
    /Users/matthew.wallace/Dropbox/dev/haxe/HelloWorld/Export/android/release/bin/deps/facebook/src/org/haxe/extension/facebook/LogInWrapper.java:7: error: package com.facebook does not exist
    import com.facebook.AccessToken;
                       ^
    /Users/matthew.wallace/Dropbox/dev/haxe/HelloWorld/Export/android/release/bin/deps/facebook/src/org/haxe/extension/facebook/LogInWrapper.java:8: error: package com.facebook does not exist
    import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
                       ^
    /Users/matthew.wallace/Dropbox/dev/haxe/HelloWorld/Export/android/release/bin/deps/facebook/src/org/haxe/extension/facebook/LogInWrapper.java:9: error: package com.facebook does not exist
    import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
                       ^
    /Users/matthew.wallace/Dropbox/dev/haxe/HelloWorld/Export/android/release/bin/deps/facebook/src/org/haxe/extension/facebook/LogInWrapper.java:10: error: package com.facebook does not exist
    import com.facebook.FacebookException;
                       ^
    /Users/matthew.wallace/Dropbox/dev/haxe/HelloWorld/Export/android/release/bin/deps/facebook/src/org/haxe/extension/facebook/LogInWrapper.java:11: error: package com.facebook.login does not exist
    import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
                             ^
    /Users/matthew.wallace/Dropbox/dev/haxe/HelloWorld/Export/android/release/bin/deps/facebook/src/org/haxe/extension/facebook/LogInWrapper.java:12: error: package com.facebook.login does not exist
    import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
                             ^
    /Users/matthew.wallace/Dropbox/dev/haxe/HelloWorld/Export/android/release/bin/deps/facebook/src/org/haxe/extension/facebook/LogInWrapper.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
        static LoginManager mLoginManager;
               ^
      symbol:   class LoginManager
      location: class LogInWrapper
    /Users/matthew.wallace/Dropbox/dev/haxe/HelloWorld/Export/android/release/bin/deps/facebook/src/org/haxe/extension/facebook/AppInviteDialogWrapper.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
            if (AppInviteDialog.canShow()) {
                ^
      symbol:   variable AppInviteDialog
      location: class AppInviteDialogWrapper
    /Users/matthew.wallace/Dropbox/dev/haxe/HelloWorld/Export/android/release/bin/deps/facebook/src/org/haxe/extension/facebook/AppInviteDialogWrapper.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
                AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
                ^
      symbol:   class AppInviteContent
      location: class AppInviteDialogWrapper
    /Users/matthew.wallace/Dropbox/dev/haxe/HelloWorld/Export/android/release/bin/deps/facebook/src/org/haxe/extension/facebook/AppInviteDialogWrapper.java:14: error: package AppInviteContent does not exist
                AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
                                                               ^
    /Users/matthew.wallace/Dropbox/dev/haxe/HelloWorld/Export/android/release/bin/deps/facebook/src/org/haxe/extension/facebook/AppInviteDialogWrapper.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
                AppInviteDialog.show(Facebook.instance.mainActivity, content);
                ^
      symbol:   variable AppInviteDialog
      location: class AppInviteDialogWrapper
    /Users/matthew.wallace/Dropbox/dev/haxe/HelloWorld/Export/android/release/bin/deps/facebook/src/org/haxe/extension/facebook/Facebook.java:85: error: cannot find symbol
            FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(mainContext);
            ^
      symbol:   variable FacebookSdk
      location: class Facebook
    /Users/matthew.wallace/Dropbox/dev/haxe/HelloWorld/Export/android/release/bin/deps/facebook/src/org/haxe/extension/facebook/Facebook.java:86: error: package CallbackManager does not exist
            mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
                                              ^
    /Users/matthew.wallace/Dropbox/dev/haxe/HelloWorld/Export/android/release/bin/deps/facebook/src/org/haxe/extension/facebook/Facebook.java:115: error: cannot find symbol
            AppEventsLogger.deactivateApp(mainContext);
            ^
      symbol:   variable AppEventsLogger
      location: class Facebook
    /Users/matthew.wallace/Dropbox/dev/haxe/HelloWorld/Export/android/release/bin/deps/facebook/src/org/haxe/extension/facebook/Facebook.java:126: error: cannot find symbol
            AppEventsLogger.activateApp(mainContext);
            ^
      symbol:   variable AppEventsLogger
      location: class Facebook
    /Users/matthew.wallace/Dropbox/dev/haxe/HelloWorld/Export/android/release/bin/deps/facebook/src/org/haxe/extension/facebook/LogInWrapper.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
            mLoginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();
                            ^
      symbol:   variable LoginManager
      location: class LogInWrapper
    /Users/matthew.wallace/Dropbox/dev/haxe/HelloWorld/Export/android/release/bin/deps/facebook/src/org/haxe/extension/facebook/LogInWrapper.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
            CallbackManager callbackManager = Facebook.instance.getCallbackManager();
            ^
      symbol:   class CallbackManager
      location: class LogInWrapper
    /Users/matthew.wallace/Dropbox/dev/haxe/HelloWorld/Export/android/release/bin/deps/facebook/src/org/haxe/extension/facebook/LogInWrapper.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    ^
      symbol:   class FacebookCallback
      location: class LogInWrapper
    /Users/matthew.wallace/Dropbox/dev/haxe/HelloWorld/Export/android/release/bin/deps/facebook/src/org/haxe/extension/facebook/LogInWrapper.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                                     ^
      symbol:   class LoginResult
      location: class LogInWrapper
    29 errors
    :deps:facebook:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':deps:facebook:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
    > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```